# Face Recognition with Node.Js

Tags: node.js

I need to develop face recognition system in node.js so, can anyone have any idea about it how to achieve this? I found this module which helps to detect faces https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv but I am looking face recognition. I have tried to search on internet but there is very few help available about that. I am new to this so, I really appreciate if someone guide me about this.

Comment: Do you know anything about any face recognition, without considering`NodeJS`?

Comment: Mostly people use face api or opencv for face detection and recognition irrespective of what the language is. Face api is now acquired by facebook so the only available option seems to me is opencv.

Comment: This may be of interest: https://github.com/malikshubham827/get-me-through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to node then building a facial recognition system is probably a bit beyond your scope currently. I would suggest writing a way to recognize faces in a language you are more proficient with, then exposing it's features to node later down the line.

This [article](http://tilomitra.com/architecture-facial-recognition-system/) may be of use to you, it describes how they built a facial recognition system for iOS using node as the server and Open CV for the recognition side.

There is also this open source project called [get me thorough](https://github.com/malikshubham827/get-me-through) which may be useful for you.

Comment: I am not new to node. I am new to face recognition.

Comment: I am not asking about how to write project.. I am looking for some starting point. To explain it further i am able to detect face through the module I have mentioned but to able to recognize image i need to create haarcascade from an image so i can match it with the provided image. I think it's better explain the whole scenario.

Comment: I think the article I linked to gives that starting point, it shows the process of the recognition and how they did it.

Comment: Yah I am looking into that. If I don't have any further answers I will pick your answer.

Comment: I'm sure there will be better answers, well hopefully for you anyway ;)

Comment: @khurrumqureshi Have a look at [node-opencv](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv) or my in progress [facematch](https://github.com/webjay/facematch).