# Is there any node.js library for offline facial recognition/identification?

Tags: database, node.js, biometrics

Is it possible for me to use facial recognition/identification to look for a particular person in the database with no internet access? Or is there any other better way to do biometric identification?

Answer (score 3):

There may be http://www.nodejs-news.com/fun-with-nodejs/face-recognition-with-nodejs/ but it uses Kinect I suppose, https://github.com/sklise/AppropriatingNewTechnologies/tree/master/week2 
You can also Try this http://talkweb.eu/face-recognition-with-node-js/ its using the face.com api

Mind you such questions have been closed by SO community in past [Face Recognition with Node.Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603440/face-recognition-with-node-js)

Answer (score 2):

There are bindings to opencv on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=opencv and opencv can do face recognition: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html so you can start looking there.

Interestingly the code example from https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv is a face recognition program:

```
cv.readImage("./examples/files/mona.png", function(err, im){
  // Get faces in image:
  im.detectObject(cv.FACE_CASCADE, {}, function(err, faces){
    for (var i=0;i<faces.length; i++){
      var x = faces[i]
      im.ellipse(x.x + x.width/2, x.y + x.height/2, x.width/2, x.height/2);
    }
    im.save('./out.jpg');
  });
})
```

There's also this interesting module that's a thin wrapper around opencv: https://www.npmjs.com/package/faced. Maybe looking at its code and opencv docs will help in translating opencv examples to node.

Comment: This is code for face detection not face recognition

Comment: @Alon: The sample code is for detection of facial features. Which is one of the main methods of computer face recognition. Read the second link in the answer: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I think I may help.
I just open-sourced my project. 
You may have a look, maybe it's what you are looking for.

Github: https://github.com/malikshubham827/get-me-through

Comment: I want it as a Javascript/Node Library. what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [facerecognition.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/face-recognition) before for offline face recognition. It is very easy to use. Also, requires very few images to give a decent accuracy.

Here is my sample project https://github.com/hhk998402/FaceRecogition-NodeJS

Hope this answer helps.